# Validating and filling default values in XML based on XSD in Python

Tags: python, xml, xsd

How do I fill the default value in my XML during validation against XSD? If my attribute is not defined as `use="require"` and have `default="1"`, it could be possible to fill these default values from the XSD to the XML.

Example:
Original XML:

```
<a>
 <b/>
 <b c="2"/>
</a>
```

XSD scheme:

```
<xs:element name="a">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="b" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:attribute name="c" default="1"/>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to validate the original XML using XSD and to fill all default values:

```
<a>
 <b c="1"/>
 <b c="2"/>
</a>
```

How do I get it in Python?
With validation there is no problem (e.g. XMLSchema). The problem are the default values.

Comment: I have just asked a similar question to to see if this is supported in any validation library of any language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900867/is-there-a-xml-schema-validation-library-that-supports-the-default-attribute-valu

Comment: I've not done this before, however, from [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/validation.html#validation-at-parse-time) it looks like it will 'weave' the default values into the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, here's some code

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import parse

schema_root = etree.XML('''\
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="a">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="b" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:attribute name="c" default="1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>''')

xmls = '''<a>
 <b/>
 <b c="2"/>
</a>'''

schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_root)
parser = etree.XMLParser(schema = schema, attribute_defaults = True)

root = etree.fromstring(xmls, parser)
result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="xml")

print result
```

will give you

```
<a>
 <b c="1"/>
 <b c="2"/>
</a>
```

I've modified your XSD slightly, wrapped `xs:attribute` in `xs:complexType` and added schema namespace. To have your defaults filled in, you need to pass `attribute_defaults=True` to `etree.XMLParser()` and it should work.

Comment: And why do need to wrap xs:attribute in xs:complexType ?

Comment: May be you also know how to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799838/is-it-possible-to-get-the-type-of-an-xml-node-as-it-was-defined-in-xsd