# Get type from xsd at runtime

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

My questions is semi-related to: [Is it possible to get the type of an XML node as it was defined in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799838/is-it-possible-to-get-the-type-of-an-xml-node-as-it-was-defined-in-xsd)

...but this question was not answered and it targets python, whereas I am interested in a C#.Net solution.  My question is: **how can you get a type, defined in an XSD, expressed as a type in .Net?**

Background:
If it helps, my goal is to use xpath to locate a section within an XML document, find that section's corresponding type in the supporting XSD, and finally use the type to then de-serialize that section into a .Net object.

Generally, I can de-serialize the xml if I know the type at compile-time, but at run-time, the type must be inferred using an xpath query.  I think this could be achieved using reflection, but I am wondering also if there isn't something already present in the .Net Framework I could leverage.

Stated another way, I'd like to do the opposite of this:

```
private void ExtractXsdFromType(Type type, FileInfo xsd)
{
    XmlReflectionImporter importer = new XmlReflectionImporter();
    XmlTypeMapping mapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(type);
}
```

... where rather than passing in a type to get the mapping, I'd be passing in a string to get the type.  I hope that is clear enough, but if not please request clarification and I will provide more details.

Thanks for your experience!

Answer (score 0):

> rather than passing in a type to get the mapping, I'd be passing in a string to get the type.

Given a Qualified Assembly Name, you can retrieve the corresponding `Type` object using `Type.GetType()`. For example, `Type.GetType("ReflectionTest.TestClass")` returns the type for the class `TestClass` defined in the `ReflectionTest` namespace.