# Why do I get NoneType returned in my python script when an xml tag is missing

Tags: python, xsd, lxml

Here is the xml

```
<FILE>
    <FILE_NAME>Test1.fits</FILE_NAME>
</FILE>
<FILE>
    <FILE_NAME>Test2.fits</FILE_NAME>
    <RESTRICTED>1</RESTRICTED>
</FILE>
```

Here is part of the xsd

```
<xsd:complexType name="fileInfo">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FILE_NAME" type="xsd:string"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="RESTRICTED" type="xsd:integer"
        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And here is the python code using lxml.etree

```
isRestricted=0
restricted = 0
fileName = file.findtext('FILE_NAME')
restricted = file.findtext('RESTRICTED')
if restricted is not None:
    isRestricted = int(restricted)
```

The above works but looks kludgy.  But what I really want to assign isRestricted either the value in the xml if it is there or a zero if it's not there. Right now I've defined it in the xsd as an integer but I'd rather it be boolean for the extra checking.  I tried using findtext with a default and got

Traceback (most recent call last):
  **File "file_tracking_populator.py", line 185, in 
    print "isRestricted=" + str(isResricted)
NameError: name 'isResricted' is not defined**

I tried putting a default in the xsd and that didn't work either.

When I did

```
isRestricted = file.findtext('RESTRICTED')
```

I got

Traceback (most recent call last):
  **File "file_tracking_populator.py", line 199, in 
    isRestricted );
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps "name 'isResricted' is not defined" because it is misspelled?

Comment: Does this help? [Validating and filling default values in XML based on XSD in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3013270/222914)